# Pybind11 for C++ code with mixins classes

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

Consider the files given below:

repeat.h File

```
#include<iostream>
class Name
{
public:
    Name(std::string firstName, std::string lastName)
      : firstName_(std::move(firstName))
      , lastName_(std::move(lastName)) {
          std::cout<<"base constructor called\n";
      }   

   void print() const
    {   
        std::cout << lastName_ << ", " << firstName_ << '\n';
    }   
        
private:
    std::string firstName_;
    std::string lastName_;
};

template<typename Printable>
struct RepeatPrint : Printable
{
    explicit RepeatPrint(Printable const& printable) : Printable(printable) {}
    void printHelloWord()
    {   
        std::cout << "Hello Word";
    }   
};
```

main.cpp (I have embedded the python in C++ and shared the Name object)

```
#include"repeat.h"                                                                  
#include <pybind11/embed.h> // everything needed for embedding
namespace py = pybind11;
int main()
{   
    Name ned("Eddard", "Stark");
    //repeatPrint(ned).repeat(10);
    ned.print();
    RepeatPrint<Name>(ned).printHelloWord();
   
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{}; // start the interpreter and keep it alive
    py::module_::import("embed"); 
    using namespace py::literals;
    py::object py_mod = py::cast(&ned);
    auto locals = py::dict("ned"_a = py_mod);
    auto result = py::eval_file("embed.py", py::globals(), locals);
    return 0;
}
```

embed.cpp (In this file I have exposed the c++ classes to python via pybind11)

```
#include <iostream>
#include"repeat.h"
#include "pybind11/pybind11.h"
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
namespace py = pybind11;

template<class RP>
void declare_RepeatPrint (const pybind11::module& m) {
  pybind11::class_<RP>(m, "RepeatPrint")
    .def("printName", &RP::printHelloWord);                                         
}
PYBIND11_MODULE(embed, m) { 
    py::class_<Name>(m, "Name")
    .def("print", &Name::print);

    declare_RepeatPrint<RepeatPrint<Name>>(m);

// How to expose printHelloWord() so that I can called it using Name class object shared to python.

}
```

Here I don't know How do I expose `printHelloWord` Function in embed.cpp so in python I can call it using `Name class object` i.e.,  `ned.printHelloWord()`. Please note that, I am able to call `print()` function.

embed.py

```
import embed
print("pythonStart")
print(ned.print())
#print(ned.printHelloWord())
```

**How to expose printHelloWord() in embed.cpp so that I can called it using Name class object shed to python.**